# Remove button UI issue inside nested templates - Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm in a bit of trouble from good 20 hours now. I am using knockout.js and dynamically add/remove rows from html table. I am having trouble in displaying an extra column for the remove button dynamically, my template is:

```
 <table class="tg">
    <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'LineItemsBodyScript', foreach: LineItemFields, afterRender: addRowRemoveButton}"></tbody>
</table>

 //template that gets called from HTML table.
 <script id="LineItemsBodyScript" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko ifnot: isFirsElement($index) -->
        <tr data-bind="template: {name: 'LineItemDataTemplate', foreach: $data }"></tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>

//template called inside the template
<script id="LineItemDataTemplate" type="text/html">
       <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: FieldValue, visible: IsVisible, enable: IsUpdatable" class="table-column" /></td>
</script>
```

If i add remove button in 'LineItemDataTemplate' template, it renders the remove button after every column (makes sense). And if i add remove button in 'LineItemsBodyScript', it gets overwritten by the child template. My model is, List>.
How and where could i add the remove button?

```
 <td><input type='button' value="Remove" /></td>
```

I looked around and found afterRender afterAdd methods but they are not going to solve the issue. 
Note: No. of columns are unknown (therefore i made a generic class for Column-Name & Column-Value)

Comment: Could you create a working demo (fiddle/snippet) to illustrate the issue in a simple form. It's difficult to visualise the issue you're having.

Comment: Hi @Tanner, jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/br627uu5/
I simplified few things in there. I wanted a remove button <td> after each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra `<td>` in the `LineItemDataTemplate` template when it's being rendered for the last field (grootboek) for each row that is not the header row:

- Last field when: `$index() == $parentContext.$data.length - 1`
- Not header row (first row): `$parentContext.$index() > 0`

Which results in:

```
<script id="LineItemDataTemplate" type="text/html">
    <td><input type="text"
               data-bind="value: FieldValue, visible: IsVisible,
                          enable: IsUpdatable" 
               class="table-column" /></td>
    <!-- ko if: $parentContext.$index() > 0 
                && $index() == $parentContext.$data.length - 1 -->
    <td>
        <button data-bind="click: removeLineItem">Remove</button>
    </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```